# Howto Setup SIP Extension to dial Queue Trixbox

Tags: queue, sip, asterisk, trixbox

I want to create a SIP extension e.g 333, which when dial, It through caller to Queue for example Queue Number is 300. How can I setup this scenario using Trixbox WebUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dial queue number. i.e dial 300 and you go to queue.

Also you can do custom extension with dial string

```
Local/300@from-internal/n
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Trixbox or other Asterisk GUI's, however, this is more than possible using the dialplan if you're willing to edit a file.

I found [this reference to adding something like manually to the configuration using Trixbox](http://blog.lithiumblue.com/2007/07/adding-sip-aliases-to-trixboxasterisk.html)'s use of `extensions.conf`, specifically in `extensions_custom.conf`

```
[ext-local-custom]
exten => 333,1,Goto(300,1)
```

Outside of that article's reference to Trixbox's use of the `[ext-local-custom]` context, I don't know how Trixbox has implemented a dialplan for queues, but... That would assume that there is an extension for 300 that sends a user to a queue, manually it'd look something like:

```
exten => 300,1,Playback(welcome)
same =>      n,Queue(q_customer_service)
```

Note that `exten => 300`[...] must live in the same context in the dialplan, the context being the `[square-bracket-encapsulated]` title in your extensions.

If you find that `exten => 300` lives in say `[other-context]` your goto would look like:

`exten => 333,1,Goto(other-context,300,1)`